# Судя по этому списку мне еще многое предстоит

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова "списку"? Если кто-то сможет понятно объяснить правило, буду очень благодарна (грамота.ру меня больше смутила, чем помогла).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А что ответила Грамота? Запятая нужна. Судя по - отглагольный предлог, который обычно обособляется (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу). Подробнее здесь:[Пунктуация при оборотах с непервообразными предлогами](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=514.G1CEg2E3xPlKHrBExIxDglOQIhCuCenquLKl3HQWjhjeUv9bKOilbIwLdA2FT7g3CxHQSSOK4zgG3vveWPYPxoDP76ayr_pRfrx9EMcM1P4HNKdCU1Fa3SgvH44Koh9-ORy2TKJIsFnBBKgrzrqpE_fEthy4aVwu5xBETw7CF6t-LaIyBQyqXUA8uCsodtzR7CXaY_fZS1X3DsXIbYeT4w.e715020ddb8578ab8d80a584bd41d89d76a19c11&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfy1qNK6_no62JEFvW2UZjTibK6ICh6iYNbEoR8c-LynPH2mh_zXKXjId5KWWVUpYzCNkvo4FAcBFk4tW0o7v3e_-kkW_HTtkf-_OFuFNEKU_gHei2-r0x56KKFebCkZAtBV8KRNdl6IZyPNk2vj47A34GuOL2IshHr1RgBFYaMdC34Kj8RUTSfw&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRDTTdORUZYeDB1Y3lpQ1YwUnQ1VDg3OUVZdXJvRklidUdFOGU5NjNycDJXa0RHVUkzMVRyaXlkSmFhMl9qeXBLencyOWhJTU1UTlRVdmlNaXlHVHBfMy1qcEFONEs1aUd3&b64e=2&sign=c7563f7455acb52038f155ccd12af3f8&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1416479574208&mc=5.404900392278067)

Answer (score 5):

Запятая нужна. А обоснование... (Чем, интересно, могла запутать "Грамота"?) "Судя по" - это производный предлог (деепричастие "судя" с предлогом "по" стало предлогом), но так как сохраняется смысловая связь с деепричастием, то и запятые при обороте с этим  предлогом ставятся так же, как и при деепричастном обороте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Возможно, я читала не тот раздел :)