# Нужно ли обособлять оборот с предлогом "судя по"?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги

В приведенном предложении оборот не обособлен:

*И вот к этому столбику кто-то привязал огромную немецкую овчарку. **Судя по рычанию и вздыбленной шерсти** овчарке это очень не нравилось. Дергая длинный поводок, она металась от стены к стене* (Б. Акунин).

Это правильно?

Похожий вопрос задавался раньше: "[Судя по этому списку мне еще многое предстоит](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42515/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82)".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Увы, мой вопрос никому не понравился. Как говорится, никогда такого не было, и вот опять.  Ну как же привлечь мне ваше вниманье?  Пожалуй, надо создать интригу и **критически рассмотреть предыдущие ответы** по этому предлогу, там много непонятного. Вот такой примерно  был **диалог**:

– Если кто-то сможет понятно объяснить правило, буду очень благодарна (Грамота.ру меня **больше смутила, чем помогла**).

– **А что ответила Грамота?** Запятая нужна. *Судя по* – отглагольный предлог, который обычно обособляется (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит **в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу**).

**Комментарий**:  Переход по ссылке у меня не получился. К тому же  в моем предложении нет тесной связи со сказуемым. И запятой тоже нет.

– Запятая нужна. А обоснование… *Судя по* – это производный предлог (деепричастие "судя" с предлогом "по" стало предлогом), но так как сохраняется смысловая связь с деепричастием, то и запятые при обороте с этим предлогом ставятся так же, **как и при деепричастном обороте.**

**Комментарий:**  А вот это утверждение мне показалось **более чем сомнительным.** Даже обороты с «несмотря на» не  всегда обособляются, а ведь есть еще обороты с  предлогами «исходя из», «начиная с», для которых предлагается два варианта решений.

**Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.** Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем здесь отличие от вводного выражения "судя по всему", которое имеет столь же буквальный смысл и всегда обособляется?

Comment: Вводное выражение сотвествует своей тематике (источник сообщения), а в общем случае это просто обстоятельственный оборот с производным предлогом.  То, что он соотносится с деепричастным оборотом,  его ни к чему не обязывает, у него должно быть свое решение.

Comment: У Розенталя пример с "судя по всему" отнесен к  категории "застывшие выражения в форме деепричастных оборотов, выступающие в роли _вводных_ сочетаний". https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=113

Comment: Но у Розенталя в этом пункте говорится о фразеологических оборотах на основе деепричастия, здесь же обычный оборот.

Comment: Призрак деепричастия здесь присутствует, хотя глагол при нем ("могу сказать:" и т. п.) отброшен. На месте запятой и двоеточие не было бы ошибкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Прескриптум**

Что постоянно заставляет меня возвращаться к этому вопросу вот уже полгода и три дня? Желание ответить. А детальнее — желание найти обоснование интуитивному согласию с ненужностью запятой в данном конкретном авторском предложении. Да-а... В информационном стиле не получится. Но так и быть. Не загадывая наперед, получится ли вообще найти какой-то ответ, начну.

### **Первое**

Почему мне не дает покоя эта (для меня уже давно избитая) фраза: "...входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу..."?
Вот, я уверен, та ссылка, переход по которой не получился:

[**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ С НЕПЕРВООБРАЗНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОГАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

> Обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу) обороты с отглагольными предлогами *включая, исключая, исходя из, начиная с, невзирая на, несмотря на, смотря по, **судя по,*** а также ограничительно-выделительные обороты с предлогами *вопреки, за исключением, кроме, независимо от, помимо.*

Мы ссылаемся на это правило и говорим: "Тесной связи со сказуемым нет – значит, пишем с запятой". Мне одному поначалу казалось, что эта вставка в скобках не оставляет других вариантов? Может, я невнимателен или с логикой у меня что-то не так? Ведь правило начинается со слова ***обычно***. Если убрать вставку, то варианты появляются! Если бы она исключала их совсем, написали бы просто: "Обособляются (за исключением...) обороты..."

### Второе

Понятно, что ***судя по рычанию и вздыбленной шерсти*** – не деепричастный оборот и не "застывшее выражение в форме деепричастного оборота, выступающее в роли вводного сочетания" типа ***судя по всему***. Хотя, может, и правда "глагол при нем ("могу сказать:" и т. п.) отброшен".

При перестройке предложения запятые сами напрашиваются:

***Овчарке, судя по рычанию и вздыбленной шерсти, это очень не нравилось.***

***Овчарке это очень не нравилось, судя по рычанию и вздыбленной шерсти.*** Без запятой близость глагола с оборотом выглядела бы не лучшим образом (как раз из-за отсутствия связи сказуемого и нашего бывшего деепричастия). А так оборот читается как добавка, присоединение.

Почему же не хочется ставить запятую в первоначальном варианте? Ведь без запятой при быстром чтении сочетание слов "*шерсти овчарке*" можно воспринять как "*шерсти овчарк**и***". А чтобы этого не произошло, мы делаем паузу после оборота, что тоже намекает на обособление (против интонации не попрешь, хотя далеко не все паузы обозначаются пунктуационно).

<...>

Если я сейчас не отправлю написанное, то мне снова нужно будет исправлять первую фразу. Сначала она заканчивалась так: "...вот уже четыре месяца...". Потом: "...вот уже почти полгода...". Тянуть больше нельзя, шансы написать первым с каждым днем тают (особенно если учитывать, что вы, Sharon, часто практикуете отвечать на собственные вопросы).

Пока не сформированные дальнейшие мысли могут испариться от реакции прочитавших, а могут и укрепиться. Надеюсь, постскриптум тоже будет.

Comment: Александр,  большое спасибо за ваш ответ, я его прокомментирую позже, там есть над чем подумать. Я хотела сразу поделиться впечатлением, но никак не могу сформулировать его точно (как будто не хватает для этого нужных слов).  И еще почему-то кажется, что текст неполный, как будто недосказанный.  Но я попробую разобраться, тема для меня интересная.

Comment: "Обычно обособляются..." это сильно сказано. Мне из других источников наоборот показалось, что обычно не обособляется. Обороты обособляются если разрывают связь между подлежащим и сказуемым и являются достаточно громоздкими. Разница между "несмотря на" и "благодаря/судя" тоже прозр. Первое на 100% может быть интерпретировано как легитимное деепричастие (не раздельно). У остальных с этим будет проблема. Хотя "Спустя" тоже 100% деепричастие, но не обособляется. Но у него нет предлога, нет вариативности, нет лексической адекватности, как  у "не взирая, не смотря".

Comment: https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/721-252_obosoblenie_obstoyatelstv.html

Comment: @Александр Стрелец    Александр, я благодарю вас еще раз. Всё у вас прекрасно и логично  написано – вероятно, я читала вас справа налево или снизу вверх :)   Вы помогли мне лучше разобраться в этой теме,  а вот как помогли – я отвечу позже, к сожалению,  сейчас совсем нет времени. Но вы ведь подождете, правда?

Answer (score 2):

Комментарий на полученный ответ

*И вот к этому столбику кто-то привязал огромную немецкую овчарку. **Судя по рычанию и вздыбленной шерсти овчарке это очень не нравилось.** Дергая длинный поводок, она металась от стены к стене. Задрала голову,  истерично залаяла – под сводом  заметалось гулкое эхо* (Б. Акунин).

1. Я читаю ваш ответ, и **всё мне кажется правильным**, всё соответствует моим собственным представлениям. Да,  писатель прав, обособлять оборот не нужно.  Остается заглянуть **в Нацкорпус**, чтобы подтвердить этот вывод практическими примерами, и вот тут меня ждет **разочарование**: необособленных оборотов с предлогом «судя по» там практически нет, хотя я подбираю варианты с примерно такой же структурой предложения.

Вот эти примеры:

***Судя по крокусам,** весна уже была  где-то совсем близко, рядом, на подходе.* [В. П. Катаев. (1975-1977)]

***Судя по тексту в Викином мобильнике***, у ребят там не все благополучно. [Марина Зосимкина. (2015)]

***Судя по надписи на бейдже**, её зовут Яна*. [Антон Пайкес, 2014]

***Судя по запаху,** абсент был сладким ликером*. [Виктор Пелевин. (2014)]

***Судя по шуму в трубке**, он ехал в машине.* [Сергей Шикера, 2014]

**Как это объяснить?** Может быть, они ориентируются на правило, по которому оборот **обычно** обособляется.  Или нет, скорее всего, считают его **вводным** (со значением источника информации).

2. **Вот так бывает в жизни.** Человек воображает, что он вполне освоил тему, познал истину, а на самом деле у него всего лишь **первый уровень знаний**. Обстоятельства (в вашем лице, наверное :)) складываются так, что принуждают его заглянуть на уровень выше первого, так хорошо уже освоенного. Сделать это **психологически нелегко**, а не сделать уже невозможно. Там всё незнакомо, неизвестно и не очень-то уютно. **Хотите составить компанию? Тогда читайте дальше.**
3. Почему-то я знаю, что мне нужно делать. Сначала надо определить **семантику отношений** в этой двухчастной конструкции и подобрать **варианты-синонимы:**

(1) Нераспространенный обстоятельственный оборот, не обособляется: ***По всем внешним признакам** овчарке это очень не нравилось.*

(2)  Обстоятельственный оборот с производным предлогом, факультативное обособление:  ***Судя по внешним признакам** (,) овчарке это очень не нравилось.*

(3)  Вводное фразеологическое сочетание, обособляется: ***Судя по всему**, овчарке это очень не нравилось.*

(4)  СПП с придаточным условным, обособляется: ***Если судить по рычанию и вздыбленной шЕрсти,** то овчарке это очень не нравилось.*

**Начнем с варианта (4).** В СПП обособление обязательное, придаточное выступает на равных правах с главным предложением. Это означает, что оно имеет полноценное тоническое ударение и  выделено паузой, интонационно это выглядит **как логическое подчеркивание первой части.**

**Рассмотрим вариант (3).** Это только кажется что вводные слова всегда выделяются паузами и особой вставочной интонацией, но в действительности это происходит не так уж часто. Обычно они довольствуются **скромными знаками внимания** (выделение голосом только лишь обозначено, пауза произносительная).  Это неудивительно, так как интонационная структура выражает **основное** содержание предложения, а вводные слова – это всего лишь **авторские метки** внутри главного текста.

Вот и здесь такой же **минимум интонационных средств**, хотя запятая вроде бы обозначает обособленную конструкцию (такая запятая  в большей степени имеет **грамматическое**, а не интонационное значение).

4. Теперь становится яснее выбор автора. Обстоятельственный оборот достаточно **распространен**, по объему она равен основной части предложения – вряд ли он будет восприниматься  **в качестве вводной конструкции**.  А это значит,  что при обособлении он будет **логически подчеркнут**, как и придаточное предложение.

**А надо ли это автору?** Я полагаю, что нет, здесь важна именно **вторая часть**, то есть психологическое состояние овчарки. Ведь далее по тексту эта тема **дополняется** новыми фактами.

5. **И теперь делаем вывод.**  Нельзя рассматривать предложение отдельно от текста, так как   в нем обозначены средства  связи между **отдельными** высказываниями. И вот в данном случае нам важно  именно вторую часть сделать **более значимой**,  тема которой получает **дальнейшее развитие**.

Вот это я и считаю (**для себя**, конечно) **другим уровнем знания**. А вот в рассмотренных примерах из Нацкорпуса оборот явно имеет **вводное значение,** вот его и обособляют, да только вводность, как мы уже говорили, не придает ему смысловой значимости.

Всё это чувствуют писатели **на уровне интуиции** – другими словами, они-то понимают, как связаны между собой интонация и знаки препинания.  Но **логика** мышления, и уж тем более формальные правила,  с трудом осваивают  эти знания.

6. А теперь **сказочке конец,** а кто слушал, молодец. А кто меня понял или даже  хочет что-то дополнить или исправить, **то и цены ему нет**.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Здоровско!

Comment: Спасибо и вам, что помогли разобраться. (Но на самом деле спасибо, что вы есть).

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий на новый ответ**  от 09.02.2022 г.

*Бегут, меняясь, наши лета,*

*Меняя все, меняя нас…*

Итак, март 2021 года.  Сейчас бы я ответила **коротко, намного короче**.

***Судя по рычанию и вздыбленной шерсти / овчарке это очень не нравилось.***

1. Здесь **интонация простого предложения**, состоящего из двух фраз, разделенных короткой произносительной паузой.  Семантика построена по схеме «наблюдаемый факт – вывод». Соответственно,  запятая не ставится.
2. При обособлении оборота **в препозиции**, происходит его **актуализация,** которая нужна для смыслового подчеркивания первой части.  При этом меняется интонация: первая фраза выделяется ударением и увеличенной паузой.

**Примечание.**  Это общая закономерность в теме обособленных конструкций.  Сравнить: *Испуганный шумом, барсук бросился в сторону*. Обособление определения при дополнительном обстоятельственном значении причины.

3. Но разве автору требовалась  такая актуализация?  Основное содержание заключено **во второй части**, а семантика первой больше соответствует сопутствующей информации.
4. Поэтому автор **совершенно прав,** не выделяя запятой оборот. Почему это делают другие? Для большинства пользователей знаки препинания –  это всего лишь оформительские письменные знаки, никакого особого смысла не передающие и не связанные с устной речью. Правила – вот что для них главное, да только  писатели не таковы.
5. **А правила здесь и не нарушены**, так как обособление оборота **факультативно.**  В других случаях вы имеете право обособить оборот, если его выделение вам необходимо.
   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему здесь написанному, автор совершил ошибку, не поставив запятую! :)

А вы, мне показалось, пытаетесь защитить Акунина (обосновать допустимость отсутствия запятой), и все цепочки рассуждений строили, отталкиваясь от его (автора) правильности и незыблемости.
Запятая нужна: оборот явно имеет вводное значение. И я не вижу варианта прочитать его иначе.