# Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Это судя по опубликованным данным также не фиксируется.

Answer (score 2):

Если кратко, то запятые нужны для обособления *судя по опубликованным данным*:

*Это, судя по опубликованным данным, также не фиксируется.*

Обособление здесь напрашивается как минимум потому, что без него требуется полагаться на понимание контекста, чтобы определить является ли *это* местоимением-подлежащим (если мы посмотрим на опубликованные данные, то *что-то* не фиксируется), или указательной частицей (вот если судить по опубликованным данным, то не фиксируется, а так фиксируется).

К сожалению, объяснение "почему" весьма противоречиво.

Если мы считаем *судя* деепричастием, то это делает всю конструкцию обстоятельством, выраженным деепричастным оборотом. В этом случае "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup> настаивают на обособлении:

> §68. Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами, выделяются запятыми, независимо от места расположения по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому.

Если мы считаем *судя по* устоявшимся производным предлогом, то это делает конструкцию обстоятельством, выраженным распространенным существительным в косвенном падеже с производным предлогом. Тут ситуация чуть более сложная, поскольку такие конструкции не всегда обособляются:

> §75. Обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания обособляются при подчеркивании их смысла.
>
> (...)
>
> При обстоятельственных членах предложения возможны различия в их пунктуационном оформлении, обусловленные, в частности, разным порядком слов.
>
> Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания).

В вашем примере подлежащее *это* и сказуемое *фиксируется* (наиболее вероятный вариант трактовки) разделены конструкцией с производным предлогом, что мотивирует её обособление.

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Можно ли считать "судя по опубликованным данным" вводным сочетанием? "Судя по..." похоже на вводные слова, указывающие источник сообщения. Я бы тоже обособила, но считала бы вводным словосочетанием.

Answer (score 2):

**Это, судя по опубликованным данным, также не фиксируется.**

Разъяснение "Грамоты" ([Пунктуация при оборотах с непервообразными предлогами](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)):

> **Обычно обособляются** (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу) обороты с отглагольными предлогами *включая, исключая, исходя из, начиная с, невзирая на, несмотря на, смотря по, **судя по***, а также ограничительно-выделительные обороты с предлогами *вопреки, за исключением, кроме, независимо от, помимо.*

Обстоятельственный оборот находится между подлежащим и сказуемым — это тоже фактор в пользу обособления.

Диккенс, например, подрабатывал чтением своих романов перед аудиторией, и **это, судя по свидетельствам,** был даже не перформанс, а настоящий театр. [А. Л. Доброхотов, Иван Мартов. «Постструктурализм — это в основном бредятина». Читательская биография философа Александра Доброхотова (2017.02.22)]
Перевод свой пришлю, как только получу способность держать перо в правой руке, а **это, судя по ходу болезни,** может случиться не раньше 1-го января 1883 г. [Ал. П. Чехов. Письма Антону Павловичу Чехову (1882)]

P. S. Вот здесь еще есть информация:
[Судя по этому списку мне еще многое предстоит](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42515/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82#:%7E:text=%22%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%22%20%2D%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9,%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5.).

P. P. S. И вот интересный вопрос (пока без ответа):
[Нужно ли обособлять оборот с предлогом “судя по”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461880/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

*Это, **судя по опубликованным данным,** также не фиксируется.*

1. **Простое предложение**, осложненное **обособленным** обстоятельственным оборотом с предлогом **СУДЯ ПО** (значение **вводности** для этого оборота возможно).

Справочник по пунктуации: **СУДЯ ПО** (чему), предлог

Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «судя по», обычно обособляются. Климат был тогда теплее современного, судя по остаткам флоры, найденным в отложениях вместе с костями (В. Обручев).  Судя по прессе, вы упорно продолжаете работать, печатаетесь (В. Астафьев).
http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_939

**Из словаря:** 1. СУДИТЬ, сужу, судишь; судя; нсв. 1. (о ком-чём или с придат. дополнит.). Составлять, высказывать какое-л. мнение, суждение.  <Судя по кому-чему. в зн. **вводного словосочетания**. На основании чего-л., принимая во внимание что-л. Судя по цене, вещь хорошая.

2. Предикативная основа: ***Это не фиксируется***, местоимение ЭТО в роли подлежащего.
3. Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов с производными предлогами в общем случае **факультативное** и зависит **от разных факторов**. Однако в заданном предложении обособление оборота **обязательно**, так как (1) он располагается **между подлежащим и сказуемым,** при этом (2) подлежащее выражено **местоимением ЭТО.**

Названное местоимение  может иметь **разное значение** (предметное, определительное, указательное),  и только  при обособлении оборота мы **ясно прочитываем  грамматическую структуру** предложения. Остальные факторы, влияющие на обособление в общем случае, здесь **не имеет смысла рассматривать.**

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ К ОТВЕТУ**

Таким образом, грамматическая структура самого оборота, а также содержание предложения **не влияют** на обособление оборота. С другой стороны, было бы интересно определить **его грамматику**. Существуют **три возможных варианта:**  (1) деепричастный оборот, (2) обстоятельственный оборот со значением соответствия, (3) вводная конструкция.

(1) Сразу можно сказать, что это **не деепричастный оборот**, так как  такой оборот  должен относиться  к производителю действия, который может «судить по чему-либо», а в данном случае «судит» наблюдатель, а не производитель, который фиксирует.

(2) или (3)  А теперь сравним это предложение с предложением из другого ответа:  *Это,  **судя по опубликованным данным,** тоже не будет транслироваться в телевизионном эфире.* Здесь обособление, как мы доказали,  также задает структура предложения, а она у них **одинаковая.**

**Но в чем же их «минимальные различия»?** Они **во времени глагола**: настоящее и будущее.  Если речь идет о **будущем времени**, то это наш **прогноз** событий – мы предполагаем, что не будет транслироваться. Тогда это (2) **обстоятельственный оборот** со значением соответствия. А если это **настоящее время**, то это уже не прогноз, а соответствие **источникам информации** – тогда это **вводное сочетание.**

**ВЫВОД.** «Минимальные различия» в этих предложениях **не повлияли на выбор знака**, но имели значение **для объяснения**.

Если же взять **общий случай**, то влияние было бы **более существенным,** так как обстоятельственные обороты обособляются **факультативно**, а вводные сочетания обособляются **всегда**.

Но мы не видим **таких тонкостей**  и ничтоже сумняшеся **закрываем вопросы**, обвиняем их авторов в невнимательности, даем им советы и при этом чувствуем себя превосходно.

Закрытый вопрос [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463315/Верна-ли-пунктуация-в-предложении#comment480596_463315](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463315/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment480596_463315)