# Верна ли пунктуация в предложении

Tags: запятые

> Это судя по опубликованным данным, тоже не будет транслироваться в
> телевизионном эфире.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении? (2)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463312/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-2) Автор вопросов один и тот же.

Comment: @JKlen Скажите, пожалуйста, как вы определили, что различия между двумя вопросами минимальные. А вдруг они как раз существенные и могут повлиять на ответ или на обоснование ответа. Я это к тому говорю, что не надо спешить закрывать вопросы, не разобравшись в их различиях. Я полагаю, что нужно более ответственно подходить к такому решению.  В полученных ответах на первый вопрос я не вижу достаточной четкости обоснования, но тем не менее этот вопрос мы почему-то спешим закрыть, как будто все уже предельно ясно.

Comment: На вопрос о минмальных отличиях не отвечено. О ДУБЛИКАТАХ ВОПРОСОВ. Лично я понимаю Максима – он просит проверить запятые в конкретном предложении. Его интересует преимущественно этот вопрос (правильность знака).  Если  бы ему предложили краткое и убедительное обоснование запятой, то он, вероятно, не стал бы задавать второго (похожего) вопроса, а решил бы вторую  задачу сам.

Comment: Но, согласитесь, трудно разобраться в тексте двух авторов на двух страницах, заполненных правилами Розенталя, упоминанием об альтернативных решениях и даже о разной грамматике. Да, правильный ответ упоминается тоже, но потом идут длинные рассуждения о том, точно ли он правильный, как будто сами авторы до конца не уверены в этом. А предложения хотя и похожие, да всё НЕОДИНАКОВЫЕ Вот и приходится спрашивать еще раз.

Comment: ПОЗДРАВЛЯЮ  всех  участников с закрытием вопроса. Кстати, у принятого ответа НЕКОРРЕКТНОЕ объяснение (это не деепричастный оборот), да уж теперь ничего не поправишь, ведь новые ответы не принимаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Это, судя по опубликованным данным, тоже не будет транслироваться в
> телевизионном эфире.

Сочетание слов «судя по опубликованным данным» является деепричастным оборотом и обособляется запятой.

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что вводное выражение с предлогом "судя по" является деепричастным оборотом?

Comment: Потому что слово «судя» является деепричастием, образованным от глагола «судить», а слова связанные в этим словом являются деепричастным оборотом. Это исходит из грамматических характеристик, что еще сказать. Лол.

Comment: @Jim Korbett,  вопрос на сообразительность. К примеру, я говорю, что этот оборот нельзя считать деепричастным. Вы согласитесь со мной или можете доказать,что я ошибаюсь?

Comment: «Судя» — деепричастие. Слова, которые относятся к нему, — деепричастный оборот. Можно считать данное сочетание слов вводным источника сообщения, так как «судя по опубликованным данным» тоже самое, что «исходя из осмысления полученной информации». Я считаю, что здесь не просто источник сообщения, так как информация еще осмысляется. В обоих случаях пунктуация одинакова. Вводное это или деепричастный оборот? Спорить о таком — мартышкин труд.

Comment: Мартышкин труд? Это ошибочное мнение, но я больше не буду вас поправлять. Приведу только один забавный диалог, подходящий к теме рассуждений о важности точных формулировок и точности наших знаний вообще. Как бы "сказка ложь, да в ней намек". – Видите эту очень замечательную шишку? Будьте любезны, превратите ее в лягушку. – Вот, готово! – Вы подарили мне грандиозное разочарование в ваших скромных способностях! Это не лягушка! – Как не лягушка? – Нет, не лягушка! Это очень банальная жаба! Стыдитесь! Мастерство состоит именно во владении нюансами. Нюанс – это то, что правит миром.